# Is there any set such that if if take any point in it and draw an open ball of some arbitrary radius It will always lie inside the set?

Tags: general-topology

Well I have just started doing topology and I am doing open sets. So i thought of the following question:

Is there any set such that if if take any point in it and draw an open ball of some arbitrary radius It will always lie inside the set?

Well I asked my friend about it and said an example of such a set is $\Bbb{R}$ and I asked him the proof he gave me the definition of a topological space. But I was thinking when people started doing topology how would they prove that such a set will be $\Bbb{R}$

Comment: Is your question about why $\mathbb{R}$ is an example of such a set, or why $\mathbb{R}$ is the only such set (for $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology)?

Comment: Both of them are my questions@Hayden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *any* metric space $(X,d)$ (otherwise you can't talk about balls of some radius) it is true that the whole space $X$ has the property you ask for - and trivially so because the whole space is, well, the whole space. 
The empty set also has the property, again for trivial reasons.
Also, $X$ and $\emptyset$ are the only such subsets of $X$: Assume $a\in S$ and $b\notin S$; then the ball of radius $d(a,b)+1$ around $a$ is not completely in $S$.

$\mathbb R$ (with standard metric) is thus just a concrete example of this observation.

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially asking of some subset $Y\subset X$, for $y\in Y$, we want $B(y,\epsilon)\subset Y$ for any $\epsilon>0$, for $(X,d)$ a metric space. The only example of such a set is $Y=X$ or $Y=\emptyset$. As a proof, let $y\in Y$, $x\in X$, $x\neq y$. Then $d(x,y)=M>0$. Then $B(y,M+1)\subset Y$ by supposition, and $x\in B(y,M+1)$ by construction, so $x\in Y$ implies $X\subset Y$, so in fact they're equal.

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be that an open ball is the set of points inside the space which are a given distance or less (with respect to some metric) to a particular point. So if you take the whole space as your set, every point is in your set. Since your open ball only looks at points in your topological space, and every point in the space is also in the set, it follows that any ball will be in the set.
Confusion can arise when you deal with the subspace topology. Just be really careful about which space you're testing the properties of an open ball. For example, the ball of radius 1 about the point 1/2 in the subspace (0,1), is the whole subspace. Clearly it goes "outside" (0,1) as a set. But as a topological space, the open ball doesn't know there exists an "outside". It can only pick elements within the space.